# Can I have a function as a variable inside a PHP class?

Tags: php, class, function, variables, object

Is it possible to create a variable which runs a function and holds its return value when it's called? Like in the example below:

```
class Object{
     public $var = $this->doSomething();
     function doSomething(){
          return "Something";
     }
}

$object = new Object();
echo $object->$var;
```

Just because I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in test.php on line 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must initialize it in the constructor (if the value is not some 'compile-time' constant):

```
class Object {
     public $var;

     function __construct() {
          $this->var = $this->doSomething();
     }

     function doSomething() {
          return "Something";
     }
}
```

Comment: (if the value is not a constant expression) :)

Comment: @BoltClock, Thanks, that's the phrase that was eluding me. The expression itself must be constant. Even if the function returns a constant, it still won't work.